# Quantizing JPEG files using Pillow increases file size

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, quantization, pngquant

I'm trying to use the Pillow library to quantize JPEGs to decrease file size but I find that quantizing and converting back to RGB results in a larger file size.

I am saving the JPEG with the default quality of 75. I have also tried converting the source file to PNG, using pngquant, and converting back. I know that Tinypng works on JPEG files so I'm wondering if I'm missing anything.

```
test = Image.open(filepath)
test = test.quantize()
test = test.convert('RGB')
test.save('test.jpeg', optimize = True, quality = 75)
```

[Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys409.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to quantize to a palette before saving to JPEG which isn't palettised? Please also share your input image.

Comment: I sort of understand what you're getting at, but for context I'm trying to write a script to reduce the file sizes of my JPEG and PNG files. I used pngquant with good success for my PNG files, but now I'm figuring out what to do with my JPEG files. I've now added the image to the post.

Comment: PNG and JPEG are fundamentally different and suited to different applications. JPEG is lossy and suited to real-world photographs and discards colour and various frequencies  to compress images. PNG is lossless and more suited to *"blocky"* computer-generated diagrams, graphs and animations with limited numbers of colours and potentially, transparency. There is no *"one size fits all"* method that you can apply to both types and expect good results.

Comment: I see, that's really useful to know. I'll try out some other methods for size reduction. Thank you.